# Using Python XPath lxml package to scrape text in <span> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to get the text from a  tag on a web page.  Using Chrome's Inspect element feature, I see that the text I want is in the following:

```
<span id>
    <b> Armor Class </b>
    " 12"
</span>
```

All I want is the text " 12" from the above.  To this end, I have the following python code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests, os, json
page = requests.get(webString)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

monsterArmor = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/span[2]/text()')
print(monsterArmor)
```

Where the path present in monsterArmor is a result of copy/pasting the path from Chrome's Inspect element feature.

When I print it though, it returns an empty list, [ ].  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have seen similar questions, but they all seem to involve etree and the examples given all seem to have information hardcoded into them, rather than scraping it.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the page information from Chrome's Inspect:
[image]

EDIT: The page URL https://jsigvard.com/dnd/monster.php?m=Aarakocra

Comment: It looks like the xpath is not matching. I would need more of the original document to figure out why.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by original document.  The webpage itself?

Comment: Why not try css selector?

Comment: better use xpath like `//span[@id]/text()`

Comment: you didn't add url for this page so we can't test it but page may add elements using JavaScript but `requests`/ `lxml` can't run `JavaScript` and then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. BTW: it only shows how important is to put all information in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for el in tree.xpath('//span[./b[.="Armor Class"]]/text()'):
   print(el)
```

The output should be `12`.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  What is it iterating over that was necessary in order for this to actually work?

Comment: @sempersax Iteration is the safest; but if you know for sure there's only one, then `tree.xpath('//span[./b[.="Armor Class"]]/text()')[0]` will also get you there.

Comment: why is there such a difference in structure compared to what I had originally?  Originally, I just right-clicked the text and copied the xpath, but that's clearly not the correct path.

Comment: @sempersax Unfortunately, copying a hardwired xpath expression from the browser is not always reliable; that's why you should always go with an xpath expression specifying node names, attributes and/or attribute values.